# Python Regular expression return none on byte string

Tags: python, regex, string

I am trying to  RE.match on a  byte string and for some reason is returning none.

My string is coming from an ssh session to which i asign to the var output

```
output = connection..recv(65535)
```

if i print this string it shows a leading b", so i use de decode function to print it in a easy to read format

```
strg = output.decode()
```

My problem is when i perform the re.match against either var (output or string) i dont get a macth and if i practice the RegEx on Rexgex101 i get a match.

for the output var [here](https://regex101.com/r/c8CQis/1/)

for the strg var [here](https://regex101.com/r/isl1zH/1/)

my python regex is as follows:

```
if re.match(r'\|(.*)\|default',strg):
    print("match found")

if re.match(r'\r\\n\|(\d{1,})\s{1,}\|default\s{1,}[^45]',str(output)):
    print("match found")
```

Any ideas to why in not getting a match, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: You're never *calling* the decode function...

Comment: strg = output.decode()

Comment: Okay - so you've edited to show you were - and... ?

Comment: i realy dont need the decode funcion its only to print it to the screen. what i want is to performe a re.match against the output var and get a macth. which i dont and i dont understand why.

Comment: Does changing `re.match` to `re.search` help?

Comment: Firstly - the just assigning `strng = output.decode` would have given you the function itself (its `repr`), not the result... and you don't describe what input you're describing as to why it doesn't work with your current pattern.

Comment: the input is on the links

Comment: if i use the re.search as suggested by @Wiktor i get a match on the strg var, which i can live with that